# Closing the Mobiscroll Datepicker Explicitly

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobiscroll

My application has the session timeout, the application goes to the login page after 15 mins of inactive. The problem i am facing is when the user opened the Mobiscroll date picker and remain in the same page for the 15 mins, the Session timeout alert shows, but the mobiscroll date picker remain in the login page also.

Is there any way to close the mobiscroll date picker explicitly.

Comment: enter code here

$('.dw').detach();
$('.dwo').detach();

this code help to close the mobiscroll explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.dw').detach();`

to delete the mobiscroll screen from the page.

`$('.dwo').detach();` is to delete the mobiscroll from the DOM.

Comment: THank sansris for help me on this.

Comment: $('.dw').detach(); does remove the mobiscroll popup, but the screen is still dimmed, how to undim it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also trigger the click event on the "Cancel" button, which would be the same as if the user had manually closed the datepicker:

```
$("#dw_cancel").click();
```